# PowerMock + Mockito + JUnit: ExceptionInInitializerError when calling PowerMockito.spy()

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm using PowerMock in an Android Test Project that I've created in Eclipse (Neon).  When I run a basic test case I am receiving an *ExceptionInInitializationError* when calling `PowerMockito.spy()`.

Here is the stacktrace that's reported:

```
I/TestRunner(30132): started: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test.JPTestCase)
I/TestRunner(30132): finished: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test.JPTestCase)
I/TestRunner(30132): passed: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test.JPTestCase)
I/TestRunner(30132): started: testJP(com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test.JPTestCase)
I/ActivityManager(  757): Start proc 30167:com.spryfox.tripletown/u0a199 for broadcast com.spryfox.tripletown/com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver
I/TestRunner(30132): failed: testJP(com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test.JPTestCase)
I/TestRunner(30132): ----- begin exception -----
I/TestRunner(30132): 
I/TestRunner(30132): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:110)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:58)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy(PowerMockito.java:234)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test.JPTestCase.testJP(JPTestCase.java:18)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
I/TestRunner(30132): Caused by: org.mockito.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:238)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)
I/TestRunner(30132):    ... 18 more
I/TestRunner(30132): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
I/TestRunner(30132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:385)
I/TestRunner(30132):    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:220)
I/TestRunner(30132):    ... 23 more
I/TestRunner(30132): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
I/TestRunner(30132):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
I/TestRunner(30132):    ... 27 more
I/TestRunner(30132): ----- end exception -----
I/TestRunner(30132): finished: testJP(com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test.JPTestCase)
D/AndroidRuntime(30094): Shutting down VM
I/ActivityManager(  757): Force stopping com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test appid=10324 user=0: finished inst
I/ActivityManager(  757): Killing 30132:com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test/u0a324 (adj 0): stop com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test
```

My AndroidTestCase class:

```
package com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({
    MyStaticClass.class
})
public class JPTestCase extends AndroidTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testJP() {
        PowerMockito.spy(MyStaticClass.class);
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

The MyStaticClass.java class being spied on:

```
package com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test;

public class MyStaticClass {

    public static String foo() {
        return bar();
    }

    public static String bar() {
        return "bar";
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.fuelpowered.lib.propeller.test" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And finally the .jar libraries that I have included (in the build path) in the project libs folder:

- cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar
- dexmaker-1.4.jar
- dexmaker-mockito-1.4.jar
- javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar
- junit-4.12.jar
- mockito-all-1.10.19.jar
- powermock-mockito-1.6.2-full.jar

With the exception of the dexmaker .jar libraries, all of the other library .jars were obtained from the *powermock-mockito-junit-1.6.2.zip* archive downloaded from the [PowerMock GitHub project](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/Downloads).  The dexmaker .jar libraries were obtained from the [dexmaker GitHub project](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker).

In order to get the libraries to compile nicely with one another I had to modify and repack the *mockito-all-1.10.19.jar* and *powermock-mockito-1.6.2-full.jar* libraries since they had the following conflicts with the other .jar libraries:

- *./LICENSE*, *./NOTICE*, and *./asm-license.txt* files in *mockito-all-1.10.19.jar* conflicted with the existence of files with the same names in *cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar*, so they were renamed
- *./mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker* file *powermock-mockito-1.6.1-full.jar* conflicted with the existence of a file with the same name in *dexmaker-mockito-1.4.jar*, so the file was removed from the PowerMock .jar library.

Additionally, there was a conflict of the entire *objenesis-2.1.jar* library included in the *powermock-mockito-junit-1.6.2.zip* archive since its contents were already included within the *mockito-all-1.10.19.jar* library, so I did not include that library in the test project.

The test case was attempted on both the simulator (Nexus 5, Google APIs, API 21) and device (Nexus 5, Android 5.1.1).

This pretty much describes all of the project settings and sources.  I've tried digging around the internet for a while now but I still don't have any clue as to what is wrong or missing in my setup so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using maven, gradle, ivy, or similar?

Comment: none of those, I've been manually managing the dependencies and build paths

Comment: I suspect if you start using one that will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you have to pass an instance to PowerMockito.spy method. It should be like this:

```
PowerMockito.spy(new MyStaticClass());
```